# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook temporarily change email body

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin

I need to change email body using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook (C# Outlook Adding). But I need to change it only for presentation, not permanently. It means: When user select another email, click replay/forward, etc. the email body must be returned into original. I don't want change the email body permanently.

I am able to access and edit the body by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.OFFICE.INTEROP.OUTLOOK._MAILITEM.HTMLBODY%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) property but it is permanent and saved on Exchange server. Is there any other solution of my problem?

Thanks a lot for answers,
   Miroslav Jasso

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to preseve the original message body of the source item that is replied to in the replied/forwarded message that is sent out.  To do so you'd need to store the original MailItem.HTMLBody property value in a custom property within the outgoing message.  You can do that by adding a UserProperty to the MailItem.UserProperties collection.  However, there is a limit to the size of the property value that can be used and this can be exceeded if an email has a very big message body.  You may need to save the original message body in an attachment if this occurs.

Comment: OK, if I store the original message body anywhere. How can I use it when user click reply, forward or select another email to replace changed body with original one?

Comment: Trap the MailItem.Reply event and grab the reply item from the Response parameter.  The Response will be the source item which contains the original message body (wherever you stored it).